# RDSのDBInstanceClassMemoryが200MB少ない？

Tags: aws

Amazon RDSのパラメータグループに使える`DBInstanceClassMemory`の値についての質問です。

現在、RDSにMySQL5.6のdb.t2.microインスタンスを1つ持っています。
その`innodb_buffer_pool_size`はパラメータグループで下記のように定義されています。

```
{DBInstanceClassMemory*3/4}
```

この `DBInstanceClassMemory`はインスタンスのメモリと同じ`1GB`になるんだろうと思っていたので、 `innodb_buffer_pool_size`は、

```
1*1024*1024*1024*3/4 = 805306368Bytes = 768MB
```

となると思いました。
しかし、実際の値を見てみると下記のように`598MB`となっていました。

```
mysql> select @@innodb_buffer_pool_size/1024/1024;
+-------------------------------------+
| @@innodb_buffer_pool_size/1024/1024 |
+-------------------------------------+
|                        598.00000000 |
+-------------------------------------+
```

これから逆算すると`DBInstanceClassMemory`は

```
598/3*4 = 797MB
```

となり、前述の1GBという予想より200MBほど少なくなります。

こういうものなのでしょうか？あるいは計算間違いでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RDS の [ユーザーガイド](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_WorkingWithParamGroups.html#USER_FormulaVariables)によりますと インスタンスを管理する Amazon RDS プロセスによって使用されるメモリよりも小さくなります。